# Escape statements on basicCard response formatted text not parsed

Tags: php, httpresponse, webhooks, actions-on-google

I have a php script on my website and this action is linked as a webhook to it. So once the data is submitted to the server, this is the response I send in json.

```
`{"payload":
 {"google":
  {"expectUserResponse":true,"
     richResponse":
      {"items":[{ 
          "simpleResponse":{
            "textToSpeech":"This feature is coming soon! Please wait until you receive a notification about its launch! You can verify if the details collected for your entry were right and inform the creator if they weren't. Here are the details."
          }
         },{"basicCard":{"title":"This is the entry I made","subtitle":"But I couldn't submit it","formattedText":"Item: Books  \\nRemarks: McDonalds  \\nDate: 2019-02-17T12:00:00+05:30  \\nAmount: 2098  \\nCategory: Expense  \\nIf the details above aren't right, please inform the creator."}}]}}}}'
```

But none of the \n get parsed. What I actually entered in php was a double space followed by single backslash and then n but for some reason php adds an extra backslash preventing it from escaping even when I used json encode json_unescaped_slashes. Here is the php code I used to create the json.

```
            $response=new \stdClass();
            $response->payload->google->expectUserResponse= true;
            $items=new \stdClass();
            $res->simpleResponse->textToSpeech="This feature is coming soon! Please wait until you receive a notification about its launch! You can verify if the details collected for your entry were right and inform the creator if they weren't. Here are the details.";
            $items->basicCard->title="This is the entry I made";
            $items->basicCard->subtitle="But I couldn't submit it";
            $items->basicCard->formattedText="Item: ".$type."  \nRemarks: ".$item."  \nDate: ".$date."  \nAmount: ".$amount."  \nCategory: ".$category."  \nIf the details above aren't right, please inform the creator.";
            $response->payload->google->richResponse->items[]=json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES).",".json_encode($items, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
            $response2=str_replace('\"','"',json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
            $response2=str_replace('"{','{',$response2);
            $response2=str_replace('}"','}',$response2);
            echo $response2;
```

And this is the link to the screenshot of how it appears in the basicCard response
https://photos.app.goo.gl/RzG5H3VgTJfrgfB59

Comment: How are you building the json?

Comment: How exactly should a line feed get parsed?

Comment: edited with php code. I was getting those additional slashes and so I used str_replace as a last resort but if you can please suggest a solution for that too.

Comment: Do not modify your json after it's been generated. You will break it. If you need to modify the data within, do it before json_encode.

Comment: But the additional slashes come only after json_encode. The string is fine and parsed before json_encode. I checked that earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're encoding the object as JSON as an intermediary step, rather than building the object first in PHP and then encoding it. As such, you're getting some strange double-encoding issues.

Doing something like this

```
  $msg=new \stdClass();
  $msg->simpleResponse->textToSpeech="Coming soon";

  $card=new \stdClass();
  $card->basicCard->title="This is the entry I made";
  $card->basicCard->subtitle="But I couldn't submit it";
  $card->basicCard->formattedText="Item: ".$type."  \nRemarks: ".$item."  \nDate: ".$date."  \nAmount: ".$amount."  \nCategory: ".$category."  \nIf the details above aren't right, please inform the creator.";

  $response=new \stdClass();
  $response->payload->google->expectUserResponse= true;
  $response->payload->google->richResponse->items = array(
    $msg,
    $card
  );

  $json = json_encode( $response );
```

is more like what you're trying to do.

Comment: Worked well, thanks a lot! I don't know what I did wrong earlier but the array wasn't getting encoded properly when I tried something like this earlier. Probably some other error elsewhere. But thanks a lot @Prisoner!